# In Revelation 13:8, should "ἀπὸ καταβολῆς κόσμου" be translated "from" or "before" the foundation of the world?

Tags: greek, revelation, translation-philosophy

The phrase ἀπὸ καταβολῆς κόσμου is generally translated *from the foundation of the world*, and is translated this way in all occurrences of the phrase in the ESV, except in Revelation 13:8:

> and all who dwell on earth will worship it, everyone whose name has
>   not been written **before the foundation of the world** in the book of
>   life of the Lamb who was slain. (ESV)

The Greek reads:

> καὶ προσκυνήσουσιν αὐτὸν πάντες οἱ κατοικοῦντες ἐπὶ τῆς γῆς, οὗ οὐ
>   γέγραπται τὸ ὄνομα αὐτοῦ ἐν τῷ βιβλίῳ τῆς ζωῆς τοῦ ἀρνίου τοῦ
>   ἐσφαγμένου **ἀπὸ καταβολῆς κόσμου**.

Why does the ESV render ἀπὸ as *before* in this instance? Is there a textual variant that I am not aware of?